# Prove $-0=0$ using the theorem of uniqueness of inverses.

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem: Let $x$ be a real number. There exists one one real number $y$ such that $x+y=0$. Similarly, if $x\neq 0$, there exists only one real number $y$ such that $x\dot y$=1.

Using this theorem, prove $-0=0$.

I wrote down some steps of what is considered my scattered logic, but I am having a hard time forming a proof.

$0=-0$ (restating it)

$0=0+(-0)$ $\rightarrow$ existence of additive inverse

$0=(-0)+0$ $\rightarrow$ addition is commutative

$0=-0$ $\rightarrow$ definition of additive identity

Is this correct? And if so, how can I form a proof using the theorem above?

Comment: Apart from your "restating it", your proof is correct -- although I would call the last line "definition of additive identity", not "existence of additive identity", because you are using the equality $a = a + 0$, not the fact that an element satisfying that equality exists.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I wasn't "restating" it. I am not sure why I included that. Its 6am here!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $0+(-0)=0$ by the definition of inverse. On the other hand adding $0$ to a number doesn't change the number, hence $0+0=0$. That means $0,-0$ are both additive inverses of $0$. But the inverse is unique so they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how your proof is supposed to work: you state what you're trying to prove as the first line, making it appear that you're engaging in proof by assertion and/or circular reasoning.

You don't need the uniqueness of inverses (note that while the uniqueness of the identity is a theorem -- it can be derived from the axioms -- the existence of the identity is an axiom, not theorem).

$0+(-0)=0$ by definition of inverses, and $0+(-0)=-0$ by definition of identity. So $0$ and $-0$ are both equal to $0+(-0)$, and by transitivity of equality they are equal to each other.

Comment: Duly noted -- thank you!